# Ruby read a file, create a hash with a key and data, then sort alphabetically

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

I have a file like below, which I need to put into a hash:

```
GHIThree, Line, Number
DEFNumber, Two, Line
ABCLine, Number, One
```

I need to do is take the first 3 characters and turn that into a key and then the rest of the line into the value.

So when I print the hash it should look something like this:

```
Keys Values
ABC Line, Number, One
DEF Number, Two, Line
GHI Three, Line, Number
```

Here is what I've got, its a little all over the place but here it is:

```
lines = File.open("homework02.txt").read.split
fHash = {}
lines.each do |line|
  next if line == ""
  fHash[line[0..2]] = line[3..-1]
end

f = File.open("homework02.txt")
fHash = {}
loop do
  x = f.gets
  break unless x
  fHash[x[0..2]] = x[3..-1]
end

puts fHash

f.close
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: oops, sorry, I need to sort the file in alphabetical order, typed the file wrong, got it fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

```
fHash  =  fHash.to_a.sort.to_h
```

Comment: `to_a` is not required, as there is [Enumerable#sort](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort) as well as [Array#sort](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort)..

Comment: @CarySwoveland I realized that that is called implicitly. But it won't harm probably.

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way:

```
result = {}

CSV.foreach('file.csv', skip_blanks: true) do |row|
  result[row[0].slice!(0..2)] = row
end

result.sort.to_h
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
fHash = { 4=>1, 1=>1, 3=>2 }

fHash.keys.sort.each_with_object({}) { |k,h| h[k]=fHash[k] }
  #=> {1=>1, 3=>2, 4=>1}
```

The steps:

```
a = fHash.keys
  #=> [4, 1, 3] 
b = a.sort
  #=> [1, 3, 4] 
enum = b.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 3, 4]:each_with_object({})>
```

We can view the contents of this enumerator by converting it to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[1, {}], [3, {}], [4, {}]]
```

You will see that the value of the hash will change as elements of `enum` are passed to the block.

The block variables `k` and `h` are assigned to the first element of `enum`:

```
k,h = enum.next
  #=> [1, {}] 
k #=> 1
h #=> {}
```

and the block calculation is performed:

```
h[k]=fHash[k]
  #=> h[1] = { 4=>1, 1=>1, 3=>2 }[1]
  #   h[1] = 1
h #=> {1=>1}
```

The second element of `enum` is passed to the block and the operations are repeated:

```
k,h = enum.next
  #=> [3, {1=>1}] 
h[k]=fHash[k]
  #=> h[3] = { 4=>1, 1=>1, 3=>2 }[3]
  #   h[3] = 2
h #=> {1=>1, 3=>2}
```

The third and last element of `enum` is passed to the block:

```
k,h = enum.next
  #=> [4, {1=>1, 3=>2}] 
h[k]=fHash[k]
  #=> h[4] = { 4=>1, 1=>1, 3=>2 }[4]
  #   h[4] = 1 
h #=> {1=>1, 3=>2, 4=>1}
```